# When click on sidebar, change only part of the screen

Tags: javascript, sidebar

I have a question, which I can't ask directly, but will try to explain as much as I can, so you can help me.

The thing is next: I am making a project about some football league, and I have a sidebar which lists rounds of the competitions like this

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <h2>2017/18</h2>
            <h4>1st Qualif. Round</h4>
            <h4>2nd Qualif. Round</h4>
            <h4>3rd Qualif. Round</h4>
            <h4>Play-Offs</h4>
</div>
```

It's nothing much, as I am trying to keep it simple. I will make those  clickable, but I don't want them to lead me to another page, I want them just to change the part of the main container of the page.

Something just like on http://www.flashscore.com. When you click to change date, the url stays flashscore.com, but the page changes to the date that you clicked.

I know this all sounds crazy, but if you understand me, I will explain even further with whatever you need me to.

Also, I am fairly new to Javascript, but will try to incorporate it into the website I am making, as I think this is pure javascript.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to create a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). There are many JavaScript frameworks available to do this. Until one is chosen, your question as it stands is probably too broad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into AJAX, that is what you will want to do in order to grab new info from a server without doing a full page postback / reload. It will be mostly JS with maybe some CSS to show / hide content. I'm on mobile so I can't give a great demo, but I'll try when I get off work.

EDIT: looks like I thought you were asking about loading new data. Should be easier than that if you just want to change content to display. I'll post more details later

Update: relevant fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/44ka1be6/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      Stuff 1
    </div>
    <div>
      Stuff 2
    </div>
    <div>
      Stuff 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Default stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar div').click(function(e) {
    $('#content').text($(this).text())
  })
})
```

css

```
.sidebar, #content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys very much, seems like AJAX really did the thing, and I managed to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer without details, but you can make the main body of the page in an element (div for example) and write to the innerHTML when they click on a link. Depending on what you want to go in the main body, you can have it all as strings in JS, or preferably load the data through AJAX. See: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp. They have a lot of good example code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to update your container with a new static content, you can just add a click event listener to your sidebar:

```js
sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
container = document.getElementById('container');
sidebar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  container.innerHTML = "New content";
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <h2>2017/18</h2>
  <h4>1st Qualif. Round</h4>
  <h4>2nd Qualif. Round</h4>
  <h4>3rd Qualif. Round</h4>
  <h4>Play-Offs</h4>
</div>
<div id="container">Content</div>
```